# One link takes me to a different page! HTML

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2013

**CSS**

```
   <style type="text/css">
#home {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#aboutUs {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#services {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 180px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#support {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 325px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#contactUs {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 460px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#information {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 600px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#sponsored {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 755px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}

#reviews {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-left: 910px;
    top: 18px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <!-- Cheange Title of Webpage below -->
    <title>DTSU - Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Div Buttons for Pages -->
    <p>
        <div id="mainNavD">
            <a href="home.html" id="home">Home</a>
            <a href="aboutUs.html" id="aboutUs">About Us</a>
            <a href="services.html" id="services">Services</a>
            <a href="support.html" id="support">Support</a>
            <a href="contactUs.html" id="contactUs">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="information.html" id="information">Information</a>
            <a href="sponsored.html" id="sponsored">Sponsored</a>
            <a href="reviews.html" id="reviews">Reviews</a>
            <img src="pictures/mainNavBar.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </p>
    <!-- Header and Logo Combo -->
    <div id="headerD">
        <img src="pictures/header.jpg" />
        <div id="logoD"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All the pages have the same format, as this is a template i made.

The only diffrerence is

```
    <!-- Cheange Title of Webpage below -->
    <title>DTSU - Home</title>
```

that is changed to the actual name of the page.

ok so in the code above, when i click the services link or the support link, i get redirected to the home page, but the link in the url is the right one.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you sure the HTML for those pages doesn't redirect you?

Comment: ... so what's your question? As far as I can see, everything's okay.

Comment: There's no problem with the HTML/CSS markup. Is there by chance a redirect code, or is it possibly that the code for those pages is identical to the homepage?

Comment: it will redirect me to the home page. but in the url bar it says the right page. But the title will not change

Comment: Try force reloading (CTRL + SHIFT + R or COMMAND + SHIFT + R). And make sure your pages are saved. Other than that, the only thing I can think of is a rewrite command on the server.

Comment: Check your Services/Support Page HTML...may  be it contains Home Page content instead.

Comment: Try force reloading (CTRL + SHIFT + R or COMMAND + SHIFT + R). And make sure your pages are saved. Other than that, the only thing I can think of is a rewrite command on the server. – AmadeusDrZaius he is correct. I needed a force reload. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeKoch Actually, there is; this is not valid markup, as the root of the document must be `html`, whereas the markup shown has a `style` element preceding everything.

Comment: @TiesonT. Wow, didn't notice but its a style tag

Comment: @natewiley Yeah, my fingers didn't type what my brain was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: it is a html document. just the css precedes it. it works trust me im looking at it. @TiesonT.

Comment: @Kcbosco Just because "it works" doesn't mean it's valid. Browsers are designed to be fault-tolerant and will try to render malformed markup, which is why you can see your page. Your browser is likely in quirks mode right now.

Answer (score 0):

You may have mistakenly added home page content in your Services/Support Page HTML...So check for the html in these pages.

Answer (score 0):

The code is all correct. You probably have added the same contents of the HOME PAGE on the SERVICES PAGE and SUPPORT PAGE.

Just cross-check it by **looking into the URL bar** in your browser (where we write web addresses like www.google.com)

When you click on the SUPPORT link, the URL will be :
*www.yourwebsite.com/***support.html**

and when you click on the SERVICES link, the URL should be : 
*www.yourwebsite.com/***services.html**

If you find this thing, it makes clear that you have copy-pasted the same contents on these pages as well.

Hope this will help you!